# Kylin derived dimension is empty

Tags: sql

I’m using apache-kylin-2.6.2-bin-hadoop3, in Insight query, I find derived dimension column is always empty in result. But using the same SQL in hive shows that the column has value. The SQL like:

```
select trans.user_id, user.tag1 from trans inner join user on trans.user_id = user.id;
```

where `user.tag1` is the derived dimension, which is empty.

If I only change dimension type from 'derived' to 'normal' and rebuild the cube, there's no such problem.

What's even more strange is, I try another lookup table, the result is some row has value and some not, I cannot find the difference between these corrlation and everything is fine in hive query.

What the problem might be?